# $f: V \mapsto W$ : f surjective $\Leftrightarrow$ $im$ $f$ $=$ $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f: V \mapsto  W$ be a linear function. Then we know we can represent it by a $m \times n$ matrix $A=(a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n})$ s.t. $f(x)= Ax$. I would like to proof that   :  f surjective $\Leftrightarrow$ $im$ $f$ $=$ $W$.

By starting out with the definition of surjectivity I know that

f surjective

$\Rightarrow$ for all $xb \in W$ there exists at least one $x \in V$ with $Ax = b$

$\Rightarrow$ $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$ span $W$  using the definition of the linear span

Know I was stuck so I searched in a book and found that the next step would be to conclude that $rank$ $A$ $=$ $m $ since $W$ is spanned by $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$. And this causes some trouble for me since if I have $n$ column vector that span $W$ but $rank$ $A$ $=$ $m$ wouldn't that mean that $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$ includes $n-m$ linear dependent column vectors? I really struggle with this stepp could someone provide me an insight?

Comment: I don't get your point. The fact that $im$ $f=W$ is the very definition of surjectivity for $f$. Maybe you have other definition?

Comment: So in the definition in our textbook $im$  $f$ $=$ $W$ is not included but there is a note that it is only surjective if this holds, thus, I wanted to show it for my better understanding since it is intuitively clear for me, however, not analytically.

Comment: But how does the book define surjectivity? To prove that $f$ is surjective, you need a definition. With no definition, the adjective "surjective" is meaningless.

Comment: The definition is: $f$:$ V \mapsto W$ : surjective if for all $b \in W$ there exists at least one $x \in V$ with $Ax = b$

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $$\operatorname{im}(f)=\{\,f(x)\mid x\in V\,\}=\{\,w\in W\mid\exists x\in V\colon f(x)=w\,\}$$
and $$f\text{ surjective}\iff \forall w\in W\colon \exists x\in V\colon w=f(x)$$
Thus
$$f\text{ surjective}\iff \forall w\in W\colon w\in\operatorname{im}(f)\iff W\subseteq \operatorname{im}(f)$$
As trivially $\operatorname{im}(f)\subseteq W$, we finally have
$$ f\text{ surjective}\iff W= \operatorname{im}(f)$$

Comment: @Me Observe the above is true for **any** function defined on **any** set. It is just another way to define surjectiviy

Comment: I understand your proof and thank you but could you provide some insight on my approach above. I am still struggling with understanding why $rank$ $A$ $=$ $m$ ?

Comment: Perhaps you want to prove that $f$ is surjective $\iff$ rank $f$=$\dim W$.

Comment: I think this would exactly use the same way - $span(A) = W$